# Can I add an angular filter in $stateProvider.state template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know I can add a currency filter like this:

```
{{amount | currency}}
```

However I am generating dynamic states and because of that I'm creating inline templates. So I'm wondering if I can add a currency filter to my dynamic states like so:

```
data.items.forEach(function(item, index){
  if(item.type === 'yearlyAmount'){
    $stateProvider.state(item.alias, {
      url: '/' + item.title,
      template: '<h3>This item made : ' + item.amount (CONVERT item.amount TO CURRENCY) + '</h3>'
    }
  }
```

}

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Reference `$filter` to your module dependencies, then do `$filter('currency')(item.amount)`.

Or you can store your filter in some variable, like `let currencyFilter = $filter('currency');` and use it as `currencyFilter(item.amount)` when needed.